# cocoa :OSX : reading and writing data in existing database

Tags: macos, sqlite

i have a database.sqlite file in my project(MAC Desktop app)
table name: tbname
attribute: id(primary key), name, status

I want to read entires from database.sqlite file corresponding to the "id"attribute
and also write in the database.sqlite

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you want to write the data into the database when you've already read it from there?

Comment: I hereby grant you permission to both read data from, and write data to, your database.